# 301 redirect appends url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all visits to a site's splash page (/index.html) to a page deep in the hierarchy (/a/b/c/d.html). My redirect rule manages an empty path, but does an infinite loop if I go directly to the index page. What am I doing wrong?

It's a shared, legacy server, with static content only (no PHP). There's an error log, but it's only showing 404 errors for the mis-named pages.

I've tried redirecting to a path relative to root, and it goes to a different URL; I'm guessing the host's doing some weird URL-masking thing...

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html
Redirect permanent /index.html http://example.com/a/b/c/d.html
```

results:

- example.com -> /a/b/c/d.html
- example.com/ -> /a/b/c/d.html
- example.com/index.html -> /a/b/c/d.html/a/b/c/d.html/[..]/a/b/c/d.htmlindex.html

Note that index.html is appended in the last example. I guess it's something to do with replacing the slash - but how do I fix it!?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Firefox -- or, rather, that my browser had cached an older, broken redirect. The following steps cleared it:

- ctrl-H
- search for example.com
- right-click
- forget about this site

The redirect works as written.